# Task Spooler – Executing an Executable within an Executable

Tags: software-recommendation

I am currently using [Task Spooler](https://vicerveza.homeunix.net/%7Eviric/soft/ts/), which is a job scheduler I have installed on my iMac. I have encountered a problem in which I cannot execute a job properly.

Using a bash script, this is how I run can use Task Spooler effectively:

```
K="opt"  # Jobname
ts -S 1 # Number of jobs to run (1 or 2)

for a in *inp
do
    ts -m -L $K bash -c "nohup ~/ORCA/orca $a > $a.out"
done
```

However, I need to run an executable that then runs another file that contains an executable. Without Task Spooler, I am able to run it like this (using a bash script):

```
a=2 # First job
b=2 # Last job

while [ $a -le $b ]
do
    ./string.exe 000$a > ./scratch/paragsm000$a &
    ((a=a+1))
done
```

string.exe uses another file (that is executable) with the below command:

```
~/ORCA/orca $ofile > $ofileout
```

However, this results in me only being able to run one job at a time (need two cores for efficiency, but only have two cores) and I have to start each job individually (I have ~30 to run). I have been unable to find the proper settings using Task Spooler. Does anyone know how a solution to my problem, or of an alternative software I could use?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is a bit under-specified. However, a few simple tricks should cure your problem.

First, you should be writing shell scripts that contain the required commands. Use taskspooler to call those scripts (or the commands within them) as appropriate. If you nest your calls to `ts` appropriately, taskspooler should have no problem handling them.

```
#! /bin/bash

for var in 1 2 3 4 5 .. 30
do
    ts ./executable.$var
done
```

If you need dependencies, you can use the `-D` and `-L` flags (see [documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/tsp.1.html)).

Comment: I have added proper examples to my question. Could you please take a look and let me know what you think? Or how I could improve the question further?

Comment: I can’t parse your update. Can you create a MWE

Comment: You probably won’t be able too unless you have the required software installed.

Comment: I’ll try to create something that doesn’t require the software, but still has the issue.

Comment: I use taskspooler regularly. I meant that I can’t mentally parse your problem because it’s rather large and has a lot of unnecessary lines

Comment: I see what you’re saying. I can condense down the scripts.

Comment: I have simplified my example, sorry for the delay. Please let me know how I can further improve the question.

Comment: Why can’t you use taskspooler at the lowest level, eg on Orca?

Comment: All attempts lead to improper execution.